# Yii2. Multiple pjax in the same page. Second not working right

Tags: php, yii, yii2, pjax

Sorry my english at first!

I have problem with pjax. Can it be used multiple in the one page? 
I try to use same pjax block in two places on the page. Blocks have different ids.
Second block not working right: page do refreshing!

It working like yii2-widget. Widget starts two times on the page!
My code:

```
   public function run()
   {
      $id_performer = $this->id_performer;
      $id_city = $this->id_city;
      $QueryItems = City::getItemsByPerformer($id_performer, $id_city);

      $countQuery = clone $QueryItems;
      $allCount = $countQuery->count();

      $haveMoreButton = \Yii::$app->params['perPage'] < $allCount;

      $items = $QueryItems->limit(\Yii::$app->params['perPage'])->all();
      return $this->render('items_widget', compact('items', 'haveMoreButton', 'id_performer', 'id_city'));
   }
```

And general view file:

```
<?php  $pjax = Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false, 'timeout' => false]);
$pjaxId = $pjax->getId();
$pjax->linkSelector = '#link' . $pjaxId;
?>
<?php if (!empty($items)) : ?>
      <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
         <?php include __DIR__ . '/../catalog-item.php'; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php if (isset($haveMoreButton) && $haveMoreButton): ?>
         <div>
            <?= Html::a('Show More', ['/site/pjax-news', 'limit' => (isset($limit) ? $limit : (\Yii::$app->params['perPage'] * 2)), 'id_performer' => (isset($id_performer) ? $id_performer : 0),'id_city' => (isset($id_city) ? $id_city : 0)],
               ['class' => 'btn big dark button_show_more', 'id' => 'link' . $pjaxId, 'data-pjax' => 1]); ?>
         </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Waiting for your minds! Thank you!

Comment: i dont see where you are using it multiple times on the page the code above has only defined `Pjax` once and that too outside the loop ? add the actual code that is creating the problemt otherwise no one would be able to help you even if he wants to

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I guess he was trying to say that this code is part of widget that is called two times in page.

Comment: Yes, as I said, wiget is called 2 times by ItemsWidget::widget();

Comment: Two times on the page. I checked by php and html code that the pjax-objects and pjax-blocks have different ids!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use two pjax in one page you can do it as follow:

```
Pjax::begin([
 'id' => 'id1',
 'enablePushState' => false,
]); ?>
 //write your code here
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
Pjax::begin([
 'id' => 'id2',
 'enablePushState' => false,
]); ?>
 //write another code here
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```